# Symfony 4 accessing parameters inside twig templates

Tags: symfony4

I'm trying to get some parameters defined in the services.yaml into my templates, but I can't seem to find anything that works.
my services.yaml file configuration is as follows:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    BASE_URL: http://localhost:8000
    STATIC_BASE_URL: http://localhost:8000/static
```

In twig:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_BASE_URL}}/thirdparty/bootstrap-3.3.5/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

but it results,

```
Variable "STATIC_BASE_URL" does not exist.
```

Need help,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! Instead of defining configurations in `service.yaml`, I made changes in `twig.yaml` as follows:

```
twig:
   globals:
        BASE_URL: http://localhost:8000
        STATIC_BASE_URL: http://localhost:8000/static
```